# Navigation: Resolution of Global Costmap

Tags: ros, navigation, resolution, planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

When I set the `resolution` parameter in `global_costmap_params.yaml` to different values (for instance `2.0`) in my navigation package, I expect to get waypoints from the global planner on `/move_base/NavfnROS/plan` that are `2m` apart, but this does not seem to be happening. My map resolution is `0.05`, and the resolution parameter in `local_costmap_params.yaml` is also set to `0.05`.

Here are some sequential sample points I get from the global planner:

```
    x: 0.730995153353
    y: -4.30375223612
    z: 0.0

    x: 0.740522741385
    y: -4.32686625014
    z: 0.0

    x: 0.750001501292
    y: -4.3499985747
    z: 0.0

    x: 0.800001502037
    y: -4.39999857545
    z: 0.0

    x: 0.81506729126
    y: -4.3626947403
    z: 0.0
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197023/navigation:-resolution-of-global-costmap/) by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2014-11-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-11-15**:
I am confused. You say your resolution is both 2.0 and 0.05. Which is it?

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-11-24**:
@David Lu, Initially the resolution parameter in `map.yaml`, `global_costmap_params.yaml`, and `local_costmap_params.yaml` was set to 0.05 . Since I intended to increase the distance between the waypoints generated by global planner, I only changed the resolution in `global_costmap_params.yaml` to 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In this example, you have not changed the actual resolution of your costmap. The parameter files are overridden to match whatever the global map has as a resolution.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-11-25**:
Thanks. How can I change the actual resolution of my costmap? by changing the resolution of the png map?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-11-25**:
Yes. That is correct.

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-11-25**:
So If I want to get the Global Planner to generate waypoints with a distance of `2.0m` from each other, then the only way is to have a png map at `2.0 m/pix` as input?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-11-25**:
With the current planner, yes. Or don't use the static map.

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-11-25**:
What's the alternative beside static map?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-11-25**:
Big empty map.

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-11-25**:
Thanks for the info. So the resolution of the costmaps (global and local) is always the same as that of the static map, right?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-11-25**:
Yes indeed.